# Can't read or write on new partitiopn

Tags: partitioning, permissions

Can't read or write on new partition i created from /root partition and now i can't do anything on that partition.

when i opens its properties it show you are not owner so you can not change these permissions.

i tried to change the permission of group to admin using

```
 sudo chgrp adm /media/sandip/73b40bee-df86-4201-b60f-6e4b6d60ee0e

 chgrp: cannot access '/media/sandip/73b40bee-df86-4201-b60f-6e4b6d60ee0e' : No such file or directory
```

i first installed ubuntu recommendly but that created three partition and /root has many of the disk space than i partition /root using bootable cd, and then i created ext4 partition and now i can't copy or paste in the new partition or i can't do anything in it.

```
sandip@sandip-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l


NAME   MOUNTPOINT           LABEL    SIZE FSTYPE
sda                                465.8G 
├─sda1 /boot/efi                     512M vfat
├─sda2 /                            80.4G ext4
├─sda3 [SWAP]                        1.9G swap
└─sda4 /media/sandip/Mishra Mishra   383G ext4
sr0                                 1024M 
Model: ATA ST500LT012-9WS14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   86.9GB  86.4GB  ext4
 4      86.9GB  498GB   411GB   ext4
 3      498GB   500GB   2006MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

kindly guide.

Comment: Will you edit your question and add this information to it:  **(1)**  How did you create the partition?  **(2)** Run this command and add the output to your question: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`.

Comment: i did can you please guide me.

Comment: The image you linked doesn't have the full output of the commandline provided.  It appears you missed the semi-colon (**;**) in the command.  The command is: `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype;sudo parted -l`.  Will you try it again.  This time use the copy and paste command so that you can put the **text** in to your message.  It's easier to process over looking at pictures.  We also need to know how you created the partition.  That is **#1** of the two questions in my first comment.

Comment: Q)"We also need to know how you created the partition. That is #1 of the two questions in my first comment"

Comment: i did it using bootable pendrive. added the image as you said

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It's just one more piece of information needed.  Will you run this and add the output to your question: `sudo blkid`?  That should be enough to provide the exact steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely that root has claimed ownership of the drive.
Run this:
Code:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER <Mount Point>
```

Where mountpoint is the directory where the drive is mounted. That'll make you the owner of the drive.

If you just want to add write permissions you could run:
Code:

```
sudo chmod -R +w <mount point>
```

---

> *One machine can do the work of fifty ordinary men. No machine can do the work of one extraordinary man. -Elbert Hubbard*